# Get trouble when want to store image path into MySQL

Tags: php, android, mysql, image, path

In my Activity A, it has a listView where the image and text were get from Activity B.

**Activtiy A listView with image and text**

[image]

When the save button is clicked, I want to store image path and text into mysql through php, and image will stored in directory.

**Activiy A**

```
  public void uploadImageAndText(ArrayList<ImageAndText> listItems, final String id) {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
            try {
                for (ImageAndText i : listItems) {
                    JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
                    String type = i.getType();
                    String[] Type = type.split(":");
                    object.put("type", Type[1]);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Type[1], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    String amount = i.getAmount();
                    String[] Amount = amount.split(":");
                    object.put("amount", Amount[1]);
                    String description = i.getDescription();
                    String[] Description = description.split(":");
                    object.put("description", Description[1]);
                    Bitmap uploadImage = i.getImage();
                    String image = getStringImage(uploadImage);
                    object.put("image", image);
                    object.put("ts_id", id);
                    jsonArray.put(object);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            AddStaff ru = new AddStaff(jsonArray);
            ru.execute();

        }

        class AddStaff extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
            ProgressDialog loading;

            JSONArray jsonArray;

            AddStaff(JSONArray jsonArray) {
                this.jsonArray = jsonArray;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                loading = ProgressDialog.show(AddClaims.this, "Please Wait", null, true, true);
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
                data.put("listItems", jsonArray.toString());
                RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
                String result = rh.sendPostRequest(Configs.STAFF_BENEFIT, data);
                return result;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                loading.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }


        public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
            byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
            String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
            return encodedImage;
        }
    }
```

**php**

```
  <?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){

        if( !empty( $_POST['listItems'] ) ){

            $mysqli = new mysqli("127.0.0.1:3307", "root", "", "androiddb");
            if( $mysqli->connect_errno ) echo "Failed to connect to MySQL";/* try not to reveal too much info! */

            /* The example you followed had this line! */
            $image = $_POST['image'];

            $listItems = json_decode( $_POST['listItems'], true ); 

            /* This never gets called - should it? */
            $sql="SELECT id FROM staff_benefit ORDER BY id ASC";
            /*
                This fetches ALL ids from the staff_benefit table
                so which ID do you need? Iterating through the 
                recordset will effectively return the last one!
            */

            $id=0;



            /*
                I assume that $id is supposed to get 
                the value from th above sql query???
            */      
            $res=$mysqli->query( $sql );
            while( $rs=$res->fetch_object() ) $id=$rs->id;

            $path="$id.png";
            $actualpath="http://192.168.107.115:80/Android/CRUD/PhotoUpload/$path";


            /* Use only placeholders in your prepared statement */
            $sql="INSERT INTO `staff_benefit` ( `type`, `amount`, `description`, `image`, `ts_id` ) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )";
            $stmt=$mysqli->prepare( $sql );


            /* Save the image to disk: I prefer to use the actual path for storing files */
            $pathelements=array( realpath( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ), 'CRUD', 'PhotoUpload', '' );/* empty entry adds trailing slash to path */
            $savepath = realpath( implode( DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $pathelements ) ) . "{$id}.png";

            $bytes=file_put_contents( $savepath, base64_decode( $image ) );
            if( !$bytes ){
                echo 'Error saving image';  
            }

            if ( $stmt && $bytes ) {
                 foreach( $listItems as $item ){ 

                    $stmt->bind_param('sssss', $item['type'], $item['amount'], $item['description'], $actualpath, $item['ts_id'] );
                    $res=$stmt->execute();

                    if( !$res ) echo 'Query failed with code: '.$stmt->errno;/* Again, not too much info */
                } 
            }
            $mysqli->close();
        }
    }
?>
```

> When click image in directory, can't display image because the file is
>   empty

[image]

Comment: This error is appearing in php or java ?

Comment: In the sql you use `file_put_contents()` for the image - that will return the number of bytes written rather than the path. Also, where in that fnction call does `$image` come from?

Comment: @DurimJusaj php..no logcat error

Comment: @RamRaider what is the correct way ? When insert, I use `String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);`

Comment: The sql statement `$sql="SELECT id FROM staff_benefit ORDER BY id ASC";` doesn't get executed - is this the actual code or extracts from it? You assign `$id=0;` and then use `$id` in the `$path` variable - this will always be the same ~ `uploads/0.png`

Comment: @RamRaider I have solved the issue, but when  I check my directory, no photo in there and I see this in my image column `/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQ`

Comment: But I still can't see where you are declaring the `$image` variable that is used!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){

        if( !empty( $_POST['listItems'] ) ){

            $mysqli = new mysqli("127.0.0.1:3307", "root", "", "androiddb");
            if( $mysqli->connect_errno ) echo "Failed to connect to MySQL";/* try not to reveal too much info! */

            /* The example you followed had this line! */
            $image = $_POST['image'];

            $listItems = json_decode( $_POST['listItems'], true ); 

            /* This never gets called - should it? */
            $sql="SELECT id FROM staff_benefit ORDER BY id ASC";
            /*
                This fetches ALL ids from the staff_benefit table
                so which ID do you need? Iterating through the 
                recordset will effectively return the last one!
            */

            $id=0;



            /*
                I assume that $id is supposed to get 
                the value from th above sql query???
            */      
            $res=$mysqli->query( $sql );
            while( $rs=$res->fetch_object() ) $id=$rs->id;

            $path="$id.png";
            $actualpath="http://192.168.107.115:80/Android/CRUD/PhotoUpload/$path";


            /* Use only placeholders in your prepared statement */
            $sql="INSERT INTO `staff_benefit` ( `type`, `amount`, `description`, `image`, `ts_id` ) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )";
            $stmt=$mysqli->prepare( $sql );


            /* Save the image to disk: I prefer to use the actual path for storing files */
            $pathelements=array( realpath( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ), 'CRUD', 'PhotoUpload', '' );/* empty entry adds trailing slash to path */
            $savepath = realpath( implode( DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $pathelements ) ) . "{$id}.png";

            $bytes=file_put_contents( $savepath, base64_decode( $image ) );
            if( !$bytes ){
                echo 'Error saving image';  
            }

            if ( $stmt && $bytes ) {
                 foreach( $listItems as $item ){ 

                    $stmt->bind_param('sssss', $item['type'], $item['amount'], $item['description'], $actualpath, $item['ts_id'] );
                    $res=$stmt->execute();

                    if( !$res ) echo 'Query failed with code: '.$stmt->errno;/* Again, not too much info */
                } 
            }
            $mysqli->close();
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: hi, can I ask you here ? Why when I clcik the image in PhotoUpload folder, it said the file is empty ?

Comment: What is the contents of `$_POST['image']`? When trying to debug things like this it is always useful to print out the $_POST variables to see what fields you have and what values!

Comment: I get undefined index in  `$image = $_POST['image'];`. I have no idea how to solve this. As you can see I want to send `listView` with text and image to MySQL  but I can't even find a tutorial which are sending arrayList to MySQL. I follow the tutorial above but it is not using arraylist

Comment: Ok - undefined index means that there is no `image` field in the POSTed data - the example you followed had a `$_POST['mage']` reference. Add `echo '<pre>',print_r($_POST,true),'</pre>';` to your php and see what exactly you do get in the php

Comment: I saw a lot of alphabets

Comment: hmmm. ok, `file_put_contents( __DIR__.'\debug.txt', print_r($_POST,true) );` ~ try that in place of previous cmd - open the text file and see what it says.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100402/discussion-between-tony-and-ramraider).